# Budget lines and Indifference curves: How do you figure where exactly you should draw the IC tangent to a budget line?

Tags: consumer-theory

In Consumer Choice, we frequently encounter budget lines and indifference curves. For a given budget line, the optimization point is at the point where the indifference curve is just tangent to the budget line. For example, here is a graph used to illustrate how inferior goods behave with increases in income:

[image]

Here, as the budget line shifts to $ I_3 $, we're shown that consumption of $ z $, an inferior good, decreases. My question is: what's stopping me from drawing the indifference curve elsewhere? Why can't I draw the indifference curve tangent to $ I_3 $, just right of $ z_1 $ so that $ z_3 > z_1 $?

Sure, the MRS should be equal to the ratio of the price of the goods, but we can show that anywhere along the budget line, right?

Also, I understand that we can't draw the IC in a way that they intersect. So, I can't draw the IC for $ I_3 $ towards the end of $ I_3 $ (near the x-axis) because it'll intersect other indifference curves -- but how do we know where to draw the IC?

In other words, I can only reproduce this diagram for inferior goods because I've seen it. If I had to graphically represent this without having seen it earlier, there is no way I'd have figured that $ z_3 $ is lesser than $ z_1 $.

Comment: Please let me know if I can improve my question.

Comment: You have answered the question. The ratio of the prices is equal to the MRS.

Answer (score 0):

In order to know the exact bundle for that maximizes utility, you need to know what the consumer's preferences are. Nevertheless, if you knew that good $z$ is an inferior good for this particular consumer at **her current income level**, you should still be able to draw this diagram. The only thing you need is to recall the definition of an inferior good: a good is said to be inferior if as income increases its consumption decreases. This alone implies that $z_3<z_2.$ Observe that in the diagram the budget constraint is drawn for three income levels. As income increases from $m_1$ to $m_2,$ consumption of goes from $z_1$ to $z_2,$ implying that $z$ is an inferior good. If income increases further to $m_3,$ consumption needs to reduce relative to $z_2.$

Note that it could have been the case that as income grew from $m_1$ to $m_2$ consumtion of $z$ increased, but from $m_2$ to $m_3$ it decreased. This is why I emphasized the role of consumer income: a given good may be normal at some income levels and then inferior for other, presumably larger, income levels.